# service failed debian

Tags: debian, command-line, systemd, services

I'm trying to start 3 services with the following command :

```
systemctl start netmet.service
systemctl start netmetSECURE.service
systemctl start netmetDUP.service
```

the problem is that the 2 first services can start and `[OK]` appears for both but for the third I got `[FAILED]`

I try to check log and no more informations about what's wrong with this service

```
systemd[1]: Starting (null)...
su[10233]: Successful su for netmet by root
su[10233]: + ??? root:netmet
su[10233]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user netmet by (uid=0)
su[10233]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user netmet
su[10237]: Successful su for netmet by root
su[10237]: + ??? root:netmet
su[10237]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user netmet by (uid=0)
su[10237]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user netmet
netmetDUP[10231]: Starting netMET-DUP (Port duplication.) services:  [FAILED]
systemd[1]: netmetDUP.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Failed to start (null).
systemd[1]: Unit netmetDUP.service entered failed state.
```

Does someone got an idea ?? thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Try naming it: netmet_DUP

Have you tried to contact Netmet?

> The development of the new version of the collector and the
>   maintenance of the new distribution are ensured by Karol Proch (Master
>   of Conferences at the University of Lorraine).

Karol.Proch[at sign]univ-lorraine.fr

Comment: Thanks but i tried to rename the file still doesn't work i think i will contact netmet